# How to add other gradle file from root directory of project in andorid

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my project there 3 sub modules are included and that's why I make one `other.gradle` file to take all dependencies and other requirements and then add this `gradle` file to my application `build.gradle` that is working fine if I have added `other.gradle` file within `app` folder 
below is my `other.gradle` and `build.grdale`

`other.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:3.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
}
```

`build.grdale`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: 'extgradles/other.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cj.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

I placed my `other.gradle` file in `extgradles` folder in app folder in anatomy of Android Studio Project . 
How can we add `other.gradle` from root directory (folder) in `build.gradle`?

I just want to add my resource `other.gradle` in root folder of application and want to access it in `build.gradle` and its working if I have added it in 'app' folder.but how to pass path from root folder in `build.gradle` , you can see second line of build.gradle thats fullfill your statment

Answer (score 1):

`compile` method cannot be found before `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`, so you cannot add dependencies in root gradle file.

Comment: could you please provide any references  for this.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/DependencyHandler.html `compile`, `debugCompile`, `testCompile` depends on plugin 'java'

Comment: i just want to add my resource other.gradle in root folder of application and want to access it in build.gradle and its working if I have added it in 'app' folder.but how to pass path from root folder in build.gradle , you can see second line of build.gradle thats fullfill your statment.